# How to get Layout instance's URL in Liferay? What is friendly URL base?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

Suppose I have Layout instance (in Java or JSP) and I want to get it's URL.

Layout represents a page. Page has "friendly URL" and I can get it by `friendlyURL` property.

But what about FULL url?

I can also get `scopeGroup`'s friendly url, where

```
Group scopeGroup = themeDisplay.getScopeGroup();
```

and obtain more short part, which is also not full.

```
Company.getPortalURL
```

also does not contain all other text (does not include port and "/web" parts).

Inside `\ROOT\html\portlet\layouts_admin\layout\details.jsp` I found the following code to build it

```
    boolean privateLayout = ((Boolean)renderRequest.getAttribute("edit_pages.jsp-privateLayout")).booleanValue();
    Layout selLayout = (Layout)renderRequest.getAttribute("edit_pages.jsp-selLayout");

    StringBuilder friendlyURLBase = new StringBuilder();
    friendlyURLBase.append(themeDisplay.getPortalURL());


    LayoutSet layoutSet = selLayout.getLayoutSet();

    String virtualHostname = layoutSet.getVirtualHostname();

    if (Validator.isNull(virtualHostname) || (friendlyURLBase.indexOf(virtualHostname) == -1)) {
        friendlyURLBase.append(scopeGroup.getPathFriendlyURL(privateLayout, themeDisplay));
        friendlyURLBase.append(scopeGroup.getFriendlyURL());
    }
```

but this code is based on strange parameters `edit_pages.jsp-privateLayout` and `edit_pages.jsp-selLayout` which I am afraid will not be accessible in normal portlet.

So, how to obtain FULL URL of page instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
PortalUtil.getLayoutFullURL(layout, themeDisplay)
```

Comment: BTW, have a look at the `PortalUtil` service: it has a lot of interesting utility methods :-)

Comment: Yes they put everything in different places: in `...ServiceUtil` classes, in variables, in JSP custom tags, in properties, in methods and also in `PortalUtil`. Forgot to search there.